# ng-repeat in custom directive: Syntax Error: Token '$index' is unexpected

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, this fails with an error:

```html
<my-directive ng-repeat="foo in foos" foo="foo" my-index="{{$index}}"/>
```

Error message:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '$index' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{$index}}] starting at [$index}}].
```

Here's the directive:

```js
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { foo: '=', myIndex: '=' },
        templateUrl: 'directives/myDirective.html'
    };
});
```

This only appears to be an issue with custom directives. If I try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in foos" style="padding: {{$index}}px;">
    index == {{$index}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using `=` to declare your isolated scope property, Angular is expecting a property that is not interpolated:

In order to inject the `$index` value as the interpolated value change to `@`:

```
scope: { foo: '=', myIndex: '@' },
```

And then use:

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="foo in foos" foo="foo" my-index="{{$index}}"/>
```

Comment: If I do that, it just gets the literal string `"$index"` (without quotes) rather than the value of `$index`. How to I make Angular expect a property that is interpolated?

Comment: Change the `=` to an `@`.  That is a literal, interpolated value.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I noticed you updated your answer with that, however it should be noted that with `myIndex: '='`, and `my-index="$index"`, the literal string `$index` is passed, so the first part of your answer doesn't help.